# reversing part of array between two indexes

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that reverses the inputs in an array between two specific indexes. However, it keeps returning the original array as though nothing changed when it is tested. Any thoughts?

```
public static void reverse (char[] ar, int i, int j) {
    char[] arTwo= new char[ar.length]; 
    for (int x =0; x < ar.length; x++){     
        arTwo[x]= ar[x];
    }
    int up =i;
    int down = j;
    while (up> j ) {
        ar[up] = arTwo[down];
        up++;
        down--;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is variable `countUp`?

Comment: it was poor editing, supposed to be up not countup.

Comment: Shouldn't your while loop have the condition `up<down` and not `up>j`?

Answer (score 4):

The `while` loop loops while the condition is `true`, but assuming `i < j`, `up > j` is `false` from the start, so no iterations take place.

Try

```
while (up < down) {
```

so `up` meets `down` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just swap the items in the original array?

```
for (int x=0; x<(j-i)/2; x++)
{
    int index1 = i+x;
    int index2 = j-x;
    char temp = ar[index1];
    ar[index1] = ar[index2];
    ar[index2] = temp;
}
```